# Minor versions for SharePoint custom list

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2007, versioning

I've developed a SharePoint 2007 custom list with a single custom content type derived from Item. The problem is that I only get major versions when enabling versioning on the list. Is it possible to get minor version on a custom list? If not, does anyone know of a post explaining a good approach around how this might be accomplished for a custom list.

Answer (score 3):

Minor versions are only available for lists based on SPDocumentLibrary - that is to say, the SPListItems must have an associated SPFile. I think you're out of luck on this unless you decide to implement the minor version as a custom column and maintain it using a custom ItemEventReceiver. Yuck.